# Javascript string.replace() for replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do a querystring replace in javascript:

```
s = "http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?&level_to_load=2#;"
s.replace('level_to_load=\d','HELLO')
"http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?&level_to_load=2#;"
```

The result I want is:

```
"http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?&HELLO#;"
```

What would be the correct regex to use, over `level_to_load=\d` ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a regex, not a string:

```
s.replace(/level_to_load=\d/,'HELLO')
```